# go interface trans to different struct and deal with map

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a check user input func that can fit more other func to use it to check params from different interface.
I have two interface :

```
type Interface1Input struct {
   Name string
   Age int
   Address string
}
```

```
type Interface2Input struct {
   Name string
   Phone string
   Gender string
}
```

Then, for the func, my idea is create a `map[string]string` to store the params I wanna check. the key is parms name, value is its type:

```
func main(){
   var input Interface1Input
   // suppose to check address and age
   paramsMap := make(map[string]string)
   paramsMap["age"] = "int"
   paramsMap["address"] = "string"
   CheckParams(input, paramsMap)
}
```

For checkParams func, cause I need to deal different interface, the input must be interface? I'm stucked, the map key cannot be used by a struct. Or if here have other ways in GO? I'm trying to trans interface to map, but it is unworthy

```
func checkParams(input interface{}, paramsWithType map[string]string){
   switch input.(type) {
    case Interface1Input:
        if req, ok := input.(Interface1Input); ok {
            for k,v := range paramsWithType {

                if v == "string" {
                    if req.k == "" {
                        fmt.Println("error")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use reflection to access fields of `input` if it's a struct, the `paramsWithType` is not even needed. Although you'd be better of creating different `checkParams()` functions for different inputs, you could also make it a method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a map, declare a struct method for each InterfaceType and use that to do the validation

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Interface1Input struct {
    Name    string
    Age     int
    Address string
}

func (c Interface1Input) Check() bool {
    return len(c.Name) > 1 && c.Age != 0 && len(c.Address) > 1
}

type Interface2Input struct {
    Name   string
    Phone  string
    Gender string
}

func (c Interface2Input) Check() bool {
    return len(c.Name) > 1 && len(c.Phone) > 0 && len(c.Gender) == 1
}

func main() {
    var a Interface1Input = Interface1Input{"Frank", 90, "1 Exclusive Avenue, San Bernadio, AZ"}
    var b Interface2Input = Interface2Input{"Margo", "01881 4940 4990", "Q"}
    

    fmt.Println(a.Check())
    fmt.Println(b.Check())

}
```